# Converting Google Geolocation API to Mapquest - County

Tags: json, google-maps, geocoding

I have a website that uses mapquest to get information based on a users postcode but I can't get the County record.  Here is my code:

```
$mapping = file_get_contents("http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=****&postalCode=" . urlencode($postcode) . "&country=GB");
$geocodes = json_decode($mapping);

if($geocodes->info->statuscode === 0){
$lat = $geocodes->results[0]->locations[0]->latLng->lat;
$lon = $geocodes->results[0]->locations[0]->latLng->lng;
$city = $geocodes->results[0]->locations[0]->adminArea5;
$county = $geocodes->results[0]->locations[0]->adminArea4;
```

Does anyone know how I can get adminArea4 to work?

Comment: In what way is it against Google's TOS? Are you doing these requests without displaying the results on a public facing map?

Comment: Yes - I want to store the lon, lat, town and county in a database

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your attempt, there is simply no guarantee that adminArea4 will be returned

Comment: Thanks @Dr.Molle - Looks like I'll have to rethink what data I actually need and maybe remove the county